# C++ Linked List Inserting Char by Char of a word

Tags: c++, string, linked-list, char

I am having trouble for a homework assignment passing a object which already has a string inserted into it as a linked list of characters (like H-E-L-L-O) and then passing that list into another object.

I can get the first word in as a list by itself (see function InsertWord), but if I want to put a second word into it (Insert), I don't know how to. Here is my code.

I feel like it's something simple that I keep missing.

```
struct Character {
    string symbol;
    Character *next;
};

class Word {
public:
    Word();
    Word::~Word();
    void InsertWord(const string&);
    void Insert(const Word&, int slot);
    void Remove(const string&);

private:
    Character *front;
    Character *back;
    int count;
};

void Word::InsertWord(const string& key) {          
    int ln = key.length();
    for (int n = 0; n < ln; n++) {
        if (front == 0) {
            front = new Character;
            front->symbol = key[n];
            front->next = 0;
            back = front;
        } else {
            Character *p = new Character;

            p->symbol = key[n];
            p->next = front;
            front = p;
        }
    }
}

void Word::InsertInto(const Word &key, int slot) {
    if (slot = 0 || 1) {    
        if (front == 0) {
            front->symbol = key.p; //this is where I lose it
            front->next = 0;
            back = front;
        } else {
            p->symbol = key[n];
            p->next = front;
            front = p;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    Word A;
    Word B;
    A.InsertWord("45352");
    B.InsertWord("YZTHRH");
    A.InsertInto(B,1);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is wrong for more than 1 reason: `if (slot = 0 || 1)`. It sets slot to 0 and always evaluates to true.

Comment: The questions is unclear. I have hard time understanding what you are saying in the second paragraph. Also, why is a `string` object `symbol` a member of `character` class? Shouldn't that be `struct character { char symbol; character *next; }` ?

Comment: 1) Sorry if my edits seem like I'm plowing through your code. 2) Your interface is already confusing. Why would you insert a word into a word? What is the semantics of it? What is a "key" in a word/string? What is a "slot" in a word. 3)  Your front character is probably not your front character, reading InsertWord. (You set front to a new char way too often). 4) In InsertInto, key is a Word and does not have a member p. Maybe it's key[0]. But there is so much else weird in this code.

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems